# which function should i use to solve

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Suppose I have a range given below

```
400001 - 400104
400601 - 400614
400701 - 400710
401101
401104
401105
401107
401201
401202
401203
401207
401209
401301
401303
421001 - 421005
421201
421202
421203
421204
421301
421304
421306
```

And I have to find data in the given below range than tell me the easiest way to do it. 
I using in function and solving it but it will become more tedious if have more range

```
IN
          (400001, 400002, 400003, 400004, 400005, 400006, 400007, 400008,
           400009, 400010, 400011, 400012, 400013, 400014, 400015, 400016,
           400017, 400018, 400019, 400020, 400021, 400022, 400023, 400024,
           400025, 400026, 400027, 400028, 400029, 400030, 400031, 400032,
           400033, 400034, 400035, 400036, 400037, 400038, 400039, 400040,
           400041, 400042, 400043, 400044, 400045, 400046, 400047, 400048,
           400049, 400050, 400051, 400052, 400053, 400054, 400055, 400056,
           400057, 400058, 400059, 400060, 400061, 400062, 400063, 400064,
           400065, 400066, 400067, 400068, 400069, 400070, 400071, 400072,
           400073, 400074, 400075, 400076, 400077, 400078, 400079, 400080,
           400081, 400082, 400083, 400084, 400085, 400086, 400087, 400088,
           400089, 400090, 400091, 400092, 400093, 400094, 400095, 400096,
           400097, 400098, 400099, 400100, 400101, 400102, 400103, 400104,
           400601, 400602, 400603, 400604, 400605, 400606, 400607, 400608,
           400609, 400610, 400611, 400612, 400613, 400614, 400701, 400702,
           400703, 400704, 400705, 400706, 400707, 400708, 400709, 400710,
           401101, 401104, 401105, 401107, 401201, 401202, 401203, 401207,
           401209, 401301, 401303, 421001, 421002, 421003, 421004, 421005,
           421201, 421202, 421203, 421204, 421301, 421304, 421306)
```

Comment: Could you please explain it bit more what you need to find in this. Because i think one simple `select * from tab_name where col_name = key_to_search;`

Comment: Where are the ranges coming fron? Are they in another table?

Comment: alex poole no range are not coming from another table  user had provided me xls sheet where range are given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as being tedious, `in` has a limit of 1000 values, which you might well hit if you have large ranges.

If you can get the Excel data into a format where you can generate the text to form a CTE, which you can probably do with formulas, you could do something like this:

```
with tmp_tab as (
    select 400001 as range_from, 400104 as range_to from dual
    union all select 400601, 400614 from dual
    union all select 400701, 400710 from dual
    union all select 401101, null from dual
    union all select 401104, null from dual
    union all select 401105, null from dual
    union all select 401107, null from dual
    union all select 401201, null from dual
    union all select 401202, null from dual
    union all select 401203, null from dual
    union all select 401207, null from dual
    union all select 401209, null from dual
    union all select 401301, null from dual
    union all select 401303, null from dual
    union all select 421001, 421005 from dual
    union all select 421201, null from dual
    union all select 421202, null from dual
    union all select 421203, null from dual
    union all select 421204, null from dual
    union all select 421301, null from dual
    union all select 421304, null from dual
    union all select 421306, null from dual
)
select st.id, st.data
from some_table st
join tmp_tab tt on st.id between tt.range_from
    and nvl(tt.range_to, tt.range_from);
```

So you build a common table expression based on your Excel data, with a range-from and range-to; where you only have one number you can just leave range-to null and use `nvl` later to make it a dummy range; and then look for data in your table that's within any of the ranges.

The tricky bit is generating the CTE, but even doing that manually from the data you have will be easier than expanding each range manually into all the individual values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible using IN, but you could insert the data into a temp table or table variable:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (value int)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (400001),(400002),(400003),(400004),(400005),(400006),(400007),(400008),(400009),(400010),(400011),(400012),(400013),(400014),(400015),(400016),(400017),(400018),(400019),(400020),(400021),(400022),(400023),(400024),(400025),(400026),(400027),(400028),(400029),(400030),(400031),(400032),(400033),(400034),(400035),(400036),(400037),(400038),(400039),(400040),(400041),(400042),(400043),(400044),(400045),(400046),(400047),(400048),(400049),(400050),(400051),(400052),(400053),(400054),(400055),(400056),(400057),(400058),(400059),(400060),(400061),(400062),(400063),(400064),(400065),(400066),(400067),(400068),(400069),(400070),(400071),(400072),(400073),(400074),(400075),(400076),(400077),(400078),(400079),(400080),(00081),(400082),(400083),(400084),(400085),(400086),(400087),(400088),(400089),(400090),(400091),(400092),(400093),(400094),(400095),(400096),(400097),(400098),(400099),(400100),(400101),(400102),(400103),(400104),(400601),(400602),(400603),(400604),(400605),(400606),(400607),(400608),(400609),(400610),(400611),(400612),(400613),(400614),(400701),(400702),(400703),(400704),(400705),(400706),(400707),(400708),(400709),(400710),(401101),(401104),(401105),(401107),(401201),(401202),(401203),(401207),(401209),(401301),(401303),(421001),(421002),(421003),(421004),(421005),(421201),(421202),(421203),(421204),(421301),(421304),(421306)

DECLARE @minValue INT
SET @minValue = (SELECT MIN (value) FROM @table)

DECLARE @valueToTest INT
SET @valueToTest = 200

PRINT CASE WHEN @valueToTest < @minValue THEN 'below range'
           ELSE 'NOT below range'
      END
```

Comment: codeomnitrix suppose i have range 400001 - 400104 , 400601 - 400614 and 421001 - 421005 if i am using IN funtion than i have to write pin code from 400001 to 400104 than mean i have to write it manually 100 pin code is there any easy was to find the data in  range given below without using IN function

Comment: nunes7452 i just want to find all the data in below mention range that y i had use IN function even i had get the correct output but it is tedious way to write 100 pincode . so i need simple way to solve the above problem

Comment: The question is tagged as [oracle], so this syntax isn't valid.